# Raspberry VNC Server is not working

Tags: pi-3b+, vnc

So, I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I connected it to my laptop through Ethernet. Whenever I tried to connect my Raspberry, I often got this error "VNC Server is not currently listening for Cloud connections". So, I thought that maybe my Raspberry is not fully booted up yet. But, sometimes I just need to wait for a very few minutes before using it and it's connected. But now, I can't get connected at all.
Please help me.

Here I attached an image showing the error:

[image: VNC Server is not working]

Answer (score 1):

As far i know this is because your rpi VNC server is not enabled. You can enable it using command sudo raspi-config, a interface will pop and here go to: Interfacing options->p4 VNC->enable. Im assuming your rpi is headless and also not connected to a network since you are using a ethernet cable. You probably need to connect a keyboard and monitor if u are not connected to a network, if u are connected try to use ssh to do this